# How to forward request from servlet to action of struts2?

Tags: java, servlets, struts2, dispatcher

I want to forward a request from **Servlet** to **Action** like this using `RequestDispacher` like this

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("hello.action");
dispatcher.include(request, response);
```

It's not working. How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to do this you may also need to set the filter to run on FORWARD (and INCLUDE as your code shows, although you state you want a FORWARD):

```xml
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher> 
  <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher> <!-- If you want includes as well -->
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 10):

Use the code in the servlet

```java
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/hello.action").forward(request, response);
```

You have also configure struts2 filter to accept forward requests

```xml
<filter>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <filter-class>
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
  </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```