# Redirect index.jsp to a Struts 2 Action

Tags: java, struts2, annotations, struts2-convention-plugin

Related to:
[How can I set the welcome page to a struts action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39399/how-can-i-set-the-welcome-page-to-a-struts-action)

I'm trying to redirect my welcome page index.jsp to an action (Struts2).
None of options in related post worked for me:

```
type Status report
message /malelo/indexRedir
description The requested resource (/malelo/indexRedir) is not available.
```

I'm follow this **FLOW** structure:

```
http://localhost:8580/malelo/ SEND TO WELCOME PAGE
     --->  (root)index.jsp SEND USER TO (by redirect, I need forward)
          --->  (indexRedir) IndexAction.java SEND USER TO
               ---> (WEB-INF/content) index-login.jsp
```

**This worked,** but not too elegant (index.jsp):

```
<% 
  response.sendRedirect("indexRedir");
%>
```

I'm trying to do this (index.jsp):

```
<jsp:forward page="indexRedir" />
```

I'm using only Annotation, no XML files configuration, please.

```
@Action (value = "indexRedir", results = 
    { @Result (location = "index-login.jsp", name = "ok") } )
```

**EDIT**

Just to clarify, this is the http header sent to browser by a response.sendRedirect :

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Tue, 27 May 2014 16:15:12 GMT
Location: http://cmabreu.com.br/basico/
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain
```

This location (http://cmabreu.com.br/basico/) points to a index.jsp with:

```
<% 
  response.sendRedirect("indexRedir");
%>
```

And show the content of a JSP page pointed by indexRedir action. Google Webmasters Tools and some bots don't follow pages like that.

See more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302

Comment: Do *any* actions work? Also note that a forward isn't the same as a redirect; if you want to *forward* (which I wouldn't, since your URL wouldn't change) then you'd need to configure your server to process forwards through the interceptors, e.g., for Tomcat, http://stackoverflow.com/a/16123779/438992.

Comment: Yes. My system is working fine with 50 actions. I know forward is not same redirect. I want to change just because I know that. My picture is confusing people, sorry. It's not folders, is flow.

Comment: Please don't downvote without tell me WHY and without understand the question! Please DON'T delete answers!

Comment: Welcome to the world of one of the S2 tag's users; I apologize for his behavior. Can you access the `indexRedir` action outside of the forward?

Comment: Yeap! Using `response.sendRedirect("indexRedir")` in welcome page `index.jsp` works fine. By the way, your solution in other post (the link you give me above) worked. Please put it in a answer. Now I can `<jsp:forward page="indexRedir" />` from index.jsp!

Comment: DaveNewton is talking about an answer that was deleted by it's owner. I'm asking to not delete answers right above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to forward to an action you must configure filters to run on forwards; normally they don't, although this is container-dependent. For example, under Tomcat:

```xml
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher> 
  <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher> <!-- If you want includes as well -->
</filter-mapping>
```

Personally, I don't find the redirect particularly inelegant, and it's pretty standard.

The other benefit is that you shuttle people into the action-based app; with the forward your URL doesn't change. In general you'd want to disallow JSP-based URLs.

Comment: I think it's not too good do do just in the welcome page. The Google Webmasters Tools understood a `Moved Temporarily` and I don't like that. Some robots may have troubles too.