# How to forward request from servlet to action of struts1.x

Tags: servlets, struts-1

I have a Servlet in web.xml, as below with URL pattern.

```
<servlet-name>ApplicationLoader</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.test.ApplicationLoaderServlet</servlet-class>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ApplicationLoader</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.loader</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I have an Action in struts-config.xml as below

```
<action  path="/settings"   type="com.test.SettingsAction"
 scope="request"    
>
<forward name="successful" path="/SuccessSettings.jsp" />
<forward name="failure" path="/Fail.jsp" />
</action>
```

Tried below approach for forward, but did not work. got 404 Page

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/settings").forward(request, response);
```

or 
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/settings").forward(request, response);

How do i forward request from Servlet to Struts action. old version of struts framework is used.

I got a solution below for struts 2 but not for 1.1.

[How to forward request from servlet to action of struts2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119925/how-to-forward-request-from-servlet-to-action-of-struts2)

Any help on this please???

Answer (score 2):

Does it change anything if you add ".do" at the end of the path? I vaguely remember that request paths had to end in ".do" in Struts 1.x, e.g.:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/settings.do").forward(request, response);
```